# CSS Adjacent Sibling based on Child Input

Tags: html, css, sass, less

Ok, so is it possible to style an adjacent sibling based on a child's valid input?
Say you had the following HTML:

```
<div id="source">
   <input type="text">
</div>
<div id="target">
</div>
```

And here's some pseudo CSS of what I'd like to do:

```
(#source input:valid) + div {
    // add cool styling
}
```

Any solution with Sass/Less? Basically I would like to style an adjacent div if the child input of its sibling div has text entered.

Comment: Right, that is all possible, but it changes the premise of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

Sibling selectors only work with siblings, not parent/child siblings. SASS/LESS compile to CSS and are unaware of the DOM. While they have extra tools to make writing CSS easier, those tools are gone after compilation.